# Removing file extension in a for-loop variable

Tags: batch-file

How to remove the extension (including the dot) such that I get

```
file01
file02
```

instead of

```
file01.pdf
file02.pdf
```

whenever I invoke the following batch.

```
echo off
for %%x in (*.pdf) do echo %%x
pause
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Batch: Remove file extension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3215501/batch-remove-file-extension)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found this link for you for some good ideas:  [Batch: Remove file extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3215501/batch-remove-file-extension). 
But based on that, you can just do this:

```
@echo off
for %%x in (*.pdf) do  echo %%~nx
```

All best,
ember

Answer (score 0):

I know this is late but since I needed the same solution and had an issue with the solution above, I figured it may help someone else.

```
for %%f in (*.pdf) do ren %%f, %%~nf
```

Basically this solution checks for all the `.pdf` extensions and removes them using the rename command.