# Batch - Trim WMIC variable output for reuse

Tags: windows, batch-file, variables, for-loop, wmic

I hope someone can help :)

I'm trying

- to get the output of a WMIC query into a variable
- to manipulate this variable by deleting the last char (colon)
- to reuse this remaining char in my script

**This is the line which generates the value I need to work with:**

```
for /f "skip=1" %%A in ('wmic logicaldisk where "Description='Removable Disk'" get name') do
```

**Usually, the output looks like this:**

```
E:
```

Now I need to cut this variable to get the driveletter "E" only, which I need to reuse in my script.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3732947/batch-to-remove-character-from-a-string) threat which I expected to be the solution for my problem too.
Unfortunately this doesn't work for me since the output is completely empty applying this.

I think I'm doing something wrong when writing the output the %%A into a variable.

**My code currently looks like this:**

```
@ECHO OFF
for /f "skip=1" %%A in ('wmic logicaldisk where "Description='Removable Disk'" get name') do (
echo.%%A
set drive=%%A
set drive=%drive:~0,-1%
echo.%drive%
)
```

**Output of this code is:**

```
E:
:*:
:*:
```

Does somebody know what I'm doing wrong? :)

Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: use `%drive:~0,1%` here. `WMIC` has a non-standard line ending, wich results in a variable ending with `<CR>`

Comment: Hi @Stephan, thank you for your quick reply :)

Now the output is (line by line)

`E:
~

~
`

Comment: If you insist on using that method, then delayed expansion will certainly help.

Comment: `E: ~ ~ ` is because `wmic` outputs 4 lines. You skip the first, the second one is your "payload" and then there are two (apparently empty) lines. The problem is, for the eye of the command interpreter they are *not* empty, but contain a `<CR>`. In my answer I avoid them to be processed, because they don't have a second token (one of several possibilities).

Comment: This is just a note to mention that, there's no guarantee that USB drives will be registered as `Removable Disk`.

Comment: Thank you for this hint Compo!

Answer (score 1):

there are many different methods to work around `wmic`'s ugly line endings. In your case, it's relatively easy (you even don't need any variables):

```
for /f "skip=1 tokens=2 delims==:" %%A in ('wmic logicaldisk where "DriveType='2'" get name /value') do echo %%A
```

I switched from `Description='Removable Disk'` to `DriveType='2'`, because output is language dependent (in German, it's `Description=Wechseldatenträger`) and `2` is `2` in every language.

Comment: Thank you Stpehan, this is exactly what I was looking for :)